# How do I mock class instance attributes?

Tags: python, mocking

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
 
def myFunc():
    myClass = MyClass(1, 2)
    print(myClass.a, myClass.b)
```

In my test, I want to run `myFunc()` but inside `myFunc()` I want `myClass` to return `'test1'` and `'test2'` as its `a` and `b` attributes.

So I did this:

```py
with patch('__main__.MyClass') as MockClass:
    instance = MockClass.return_value
    instance.a.return_value = 'test1'
    instance.b.return_value = 'test2'
    myFunc()
```

However, the result is `<MagicMock name=MyClass().a' id='2938383'>`..... Instead of simply `'test1'` and `'test2'`.

What am I doing wrong? What am I misunderstanding about how to use mock?

Comment: Just saw that your `__init__` is also missing `self`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`return_value` is for callables, just write:

```
with patch('__main__.MyClass') as MockClass:
   instance = MockClass.return_value
   instance.a = 'test1'
   instance.b = 'test2'
   myFunc()

# test1 test2
```

And you have to `patch` the class in the with-statement, note the capital letter of Class in `'__main__.MyClass'`.

Comment: I used `MockClass()` instead of `MockClass.return_value`, which seemed to give me what I needed.

Comment: Neither of the two approaches listed above are working for me.

Comment: @pdoherty926 I just tested it again and it still works for me, now under Python 3.7.3. You have to import `patch` from `unittest.mock` in case that's unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! After banging my head against this for a few hours, I'm now thinking that my issue is probably the result of the attribute being set dynamically using `setattr` (legacy code -- not really sure why this is the case).

Comment: @pdoherty926 Might be worth double-checking if `setattr` is really manipulating the class and not the instance, because your patch should also target the class.

Comment: What about passing arguments to `MockClass.__init__()`?

Comment: @Björn I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. In the example `myFunc()`  _is_ passing arguments `1, 2` to the mocked class.